# Laravel passport doesn't create User

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to register a user via `HTTP POST request` with PHP Laravel.

Here is my `AuthController`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public $successStatus = 200;

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
        ]);
        
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
        ]);
        
        $user->save();
        $message['success'] = 'Created Account Successfully';
        
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $message
        ], 201);
    }
    public function login(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $message['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            $message['token_type'] = 'Bearer';
            $message['experies_at'] = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1))->toDateTimeString();
            $message['success'] = 'Logged in successfully';

            return response()->json(['message' => $message], $this->successStatus);
        }

        else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

And my `routes/api.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

Route::post('/users', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

When I send a POST request to `http://localhost:8080/api/users/` with name,email and passport parameters, it returns 200 response instead of 201. And it's showing the index page of Laravel, not the response. I checked the database, and user is not created.

Can you help me with what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the way you do the route. For exemple:

Route::post('users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@register');

I dont really get why you do: public $successStatus = 200;

Maybe try to remove this line.

Comment: Tried, but same response.